# How do I fray/twist small wire reliably for soldering?

Tags: soldering, lcd, wire

I accidentally severed a lcd monitor cable, and am not sure how to fray/twist them together reliably in order to solder it back? It's difficult to see all the strands, and not miss any, ime. Also, holding them tight together enough for the solder gun to penetrate heat through both enough for the solder to melt,  seems tricky, ime (that'd be in case not being able to twist them together).

the arrows point to the wire tips to be soldered [image]

Comment: Isn't that coaxial cable, maybe for an antenna that provides wireless connectivity?

Comment: Indeed. It's just a single copper wire in the middle, correct? The "small strands" is the shield and that's the easiest thing to fix. The main problem here is that patching together a coax with a solder joint isn't ideal signal-wise, though it can be done. But step 1 here is to find out where this cable actually goes and what it's actually for. You got any form of wireless electronics in the monitor or perhaps speakers?

Comment: Also, what is a "solder gun"? Do you intend to do this with a hot air gun? If so, forget all about that.

Comment: you might be better finding where it goes from/to and replacing the wire.

Comment: might be a great opportunity to replace with a better antenna too.

Comment: well, wireless still worked, while lcd showed black/white pixel region, before taking it apart..

Answer (score 1):

I would find a piece of the same type of cable to go between those two ends and then remove that poor soldering.

Join the inner single conductor by twisting then cover and seal with heat shrink.

Then join the braided outer by laying one over the other and again over by heatshrink.

Heatshrink is available that has a glue built-in which can provide more mechanical strength to the joint.

Success, in varying degrees, depends on care with the twisting - worked for me in the past but does depend on the signals sent via that cable.

You could find a complete replacement cable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no justification reasonable enough to attempt this. You'll likely lack the slack needed to solder let alone have it not pull or snap as the monitor opens and closes. Signal will be affected, your wifi or Bluetooth will SUCK. You have to strip it back more to free up the conductors for soldering and you likely won't do it without damaging the conductors more.

**This is a time where replacement is preferred. Especially on a mass produced part.**

That said you would cut back a little of the shield on one side and then expose the inner conductor. On the other side you strip back alot of the outer insulation, then pull back the shield and then expose a section of the inner conductor. Solder the inner conductors together. Add heat shrink. Fold the shield back over and solder it to the other side carefully. Add more heatshrink on top. Preferably add a physical stabilizer so that now weakened section doesn't flex. You can youtube "how to splice antenna wire" for multiple video examples.